# firefox interprete wrong my string

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

i'm converting a chrome extension to firefox, and i got the browser.action badge not showing properly when empty. I traced it and it seems firefox interprete an empty chain "" like this :

> 0[object Object]0

while in chrome i get it like this

> arg = 0

```
function updateCounter(arg) {
    if (arg == 0)
        arg = "";
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: arg.toString() });
}
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {
  var updatedValues
  chrome.storage.local.get({"count": 0, "countDailymotion": 0, "tweetCount": 0, "countFacebook": 0}, function(items){
  updateCounter(items.count + items.countDailymotion + items.tweetCount + items.countFacebook)
  })
});
```

which causes the browseraction badge to have the value

> 0[ob

any idea what this is about?

Comment: Please format your code with spaces, not tabs.

Comment: Apparently, `items.countDailymotion` is an object.